# DNS with Google Compute Engine

Tags: email, dns, server, administration

I'm using GCE as a web server for the first time. Everything is fine so far, I have installed the LAMP stack without any trouble but now is the time to set up the DNS.

My two problems are :

- I can't handle email adresses with GCE (can't send emails without sendgrid). So I would like to keep the emails going to my current shared hosting. So emails should be managed by my shared hosting but access to my website should be via GCE.
- I also would like my DNS to point to a specific folder of my GCE instance (not the root).

I searched a lot for the answer but I can't manage to make it happen.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution... Posting here if anyone has the same problem later...

```
A record to GCE : @ to xxx.xxx.xxx.111
A record to shared hosting : mail.domain.com to xxx.xxx.xxx.222
MX record @ to mail.domain.com
```

Easy. Seems to be working for me right now.